# Why does navigating to http:// then redirect to https:// give mixed content warning?

Tags: 301-redirect, https

If I directly navigate to `https://scotthelme.co.uk` I get a green TLS indicator in the address bar. If I navigate to `http://scotthelme.com` which issues a 301 to `https://scotthelme.co.uk` I get a mixed content warning. The console in Chrome dev tools can't seem to tell me what the content loaded over http:// is, how do I find / what is the cause of the mixed content warning?

Comment: To be honest, I've noticed a similar warning on other sites using Chrome recently and it does it for me too. Firefox does not. I'm wondering if it has something to do with browser extensions?! In fact, this seems quite probable... try incognito mode (which does not normally load extensions), this works OK for me.

Comment: I've noticed this too with Chrome extensions, and with tracking code, particularly ones that uses an image like a single pixel that's not served under HTTPS. Also for some (unknown) reason clearing the browser cache seems to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at your links and did the whole `HTTP` to `HTTPS` transfer, and in Dragon (a Chromium custom build) using Incognito mode, it did not issue any alerts or errors.

However, that being said, I did look at your DOM structure and you are linking to:

- **scotthelme.com**
- ajax.cloudflare.com
- themes.googleusercontent.com
- i.creativecommons.org
- fonts.googleapis.com
- api.flattr.com
- apis.google.com
- disqus.com
- platform.twitter.com

and while some of these are linked directly, some of them are linked via your inclusion of their third-party scripting. Keep in mind that when you do that, it often leaves you open to the other parties modifications. This means if they happen to link to an item that is not being delivered through `HTTPS` you will inherit this mixed content and it will flag on your end too.

When including outside sources, the best thing to do is validate the provenance (origin) of the information you are linking to and make sure they are as you expect them to be or don't link to them. Most of the time, as long as the mixed content is not malicious you are fine, but it can turn some people off when they get the warning and don't know better.

Hope some of this helps you out. When possible, put the resources you want to use locally on your own server and link to those from there. Also, given we know the very first item is not secure, linking to it is a bad idea and would most likely always generate this warning.